# Upload from GCS to bigquery using custom partition

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to upload data from GCS bucket to bigquery using GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator as below ,but the partition column (state) is populated as null.Any idea?

```
gcs_to_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
task_id='gcs_to_bigquery',
bucket=gcs_bucket,
source_objects=[
    'parquet/sample_data/*'
],
destination_project_dataset_table='projectxxxxx.{}.sample_data'.format(schema),
source_format='PARQUET',
schema_fields=[{"name": "id", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
               {"name": "col1", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
               {"name": "col2", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
               {"name": "col3", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
               {"name": "col4", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
               {"name": "col5", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},

               {"name": "state", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}],
create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
dag=dag
```

)

Comment: Try `'projectxxxxx.{}.sample_data$YYYMMDD'` in the place of your table and replace `YYYYMMDD` with your date. See if it helps.

Comment: it didnt help. state field is still populated as null.

Comment: oh wait..why do you have `state` column acting as a partition column? In BigQuery, you can only partition a table by ingestion time (which is taken care by the `_partitiontime` meta field in the table. You dont really have to add this field to your table schema. Whenever you create a partitioned table BigQuery adds this metafield to your table.

Comment: this is actually hive data that is partitioned on state and written to GCS bucket which i am trying to upload to bigquery.The above code is giving nulls for state field.

Comment: Have you tried loading using bq cli or UI? Does it work? Have you tried with autodetect? There is any message in the Airflow task log?